# Destructuring assignments

Tags: javascript

```
 var { a:x, b:y } = { a:7, b:8 };
 console.log(x); // prints: 7
 console.log(y); // prints: 8
```

Is this method of assignment valid?Will this method bring any problem?

Comment: `{ a:x, b:y }` is not a valid variable name. This should be a syntax error.

Comment: In chrome this gives: *SyntaxError: Unexpected token {*

Answer (score -1):

This assignment is just not valid javascript and will not work. This is the only problem this method will bring.

Why don't you just use

```
var v = { a:7, b:8 };
```

to assign an object with fields `a` set to 7 and `b` set to 8 to a variable v?